# why <button> also triggers a form submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my testing code:

```
<form>
<input type="submit"/>
<button >tt</button>
</form>

<script>

$("form").submit(function(){
    console.log("submit");
    return false;
});

</script>
```

The <input> tag triggers a submit as I expected, but I don't know why <button> also triggers submit. Is this what is supposed to be doing?

If <button> is supposed to be doing a submit, when what should I use if I want to create a button with glyphicons instead of plain text? P.S I'm using boostrap + jQuery

Comment: "A button element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as a button element with its type attribute set to "submit"" from http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML `<button>` accept a `type` attribute. And [as you can see in the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), the default value of `type` is `submit`, hence why your form submit.

What you want is a button with no default behaviour. Just add `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button">tt</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the default [behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement):

> "submit": The button submits the form. This is the default value if the attribute is not specified, HTML5 or if it is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.